# Center text with spaces in button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text-alignment

Recently, I've been trying to center text inside tkinter (in a button). I've already tried to use `button.pack(anchor=tkinter.W)`, but that didn't work. I want it to be perfectly aligned like in terminal, but I keep on getting [this result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tMVy67-4pXph5w4FHt21QUbcE1qCS4Mo/view?usp=sharing). I want it to look something [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKCIqoUbkxlmMVz25nRHD1fZLfOSjDtU/view?usp=sharing) when I use print in terminal.

Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
root=Tk()

button=Button(root,text="""
        |---------|
        |         |
        |         0
        |        /|\\
        |        / \\
        |
        |
        |
    """)
button.pack(anchor=tkinter.W)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a mono-spaced font and set `justify='left'`:

```py
button=Button(root,text=r"""
        |---------|
        |         |
        |         0
        |        /|\
        |        / \
        |
        |
        |
    """, justify='left', font='TkFixedFont')
```

Result:

[image]